# Terraform creating SSL cert in azure

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Hi I am having problem with creating SSL cert in key vault (*azurerm_key_vault_certificate* as in [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_certificate))
Here is code that I am using:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "app" {
  provider = azurerm.app
  depends_on    = [
    azurerm_resource_group.app
  ]
  certificate_policy {
    lifetime_action {
      action {
        # Certificate contacts on expiring certificates
        action_type = "EmailContacts"
      }
      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 28
      }
    }
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }
    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = false
      key_size = 2048
    }
    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }
  }
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.app[0].id
  name                    = "${var.app_stage}-${var.app_key}"
}
```

And error I am receiving:

```
Error: keyvault.BaseClient#CreateCertificate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadParameter" Message="Property policy has invalid value\r\n"

  with module.car2x-ntg55-adapter.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.app,
  on ../../app/main.tf line 401, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "app":
 401: resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "app" {
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code without including `x509_certificate_properties` block, I too got **same error** as below:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "app" {
  name = "${var.app_stage}-${var.app_key}"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.app[0].id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.app ]
  
  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_type = "RSA"
      reuse_key = false
      key_size = 2048
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "EmailContacts"
      }
      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 28
      }
    }
   
    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }
  }
```

**Response:**

[image]

The error occurred as you missed including `x509_certificate_properties` block in your code that is **mandatory** when `certificate`  block is not specified while creating certificate.

To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass  **`x509_certificate_properties`** block in your code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "app" {
  name = "${var.app_stage}-${var.app_key}"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.app[0].id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_key_vault.app ]
  
  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_type = "RSA"
      reuse_key = false
      key_size = 2048
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "EmailContacts"
      }
      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 28
      }
    }
   
    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      # Server Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
      # Client Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["internal.contoso.com", "domain.hello.world"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=sri-cert"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **certificate** created successfully in key vault like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[azurerm_key_vault_certificate | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_certificate#argument-reference)